# How to render invisible a picturebox in an event handler on all picturebox clicks?

Tags: c#

I have multiple pictureboxes all added to an event handler, this is the method for the event handler:

```
private void Picturemethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

And this is how i added the pictureboxes to the event handler

```
for (int j = 0; j < top.Length; j++)
{
    top[j].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Picturemethod);
}
```

All the pictureboxes are in the top Array.
How would i go by making the picturebox invisible when clicked in my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sender` parameter to get the current picture box that trigger the event.

```
private void Picturemethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var pBox = sender as PictureBox;
   if(pBox != null) 
   {
      pBox.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* thing you want to do on `MouseClick` is hide the current `PictureBox`, you could write it inline, using a lambda expression, and get rid of `private void Picturemethod`.

```
foreach (var t in top)
{
    var t2 = t;
    t.MouseClick += (s, a) => t2.Hide();
}
```

Alternative syntax, using a delegate (anonymous method):

```
foreach (var t in top)
{
    var t2 = t;
    t.MouseClick += delegate { t2.Hide(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *cast* `object sender` to `PictureBox` and set `Visibile` property as follows:

```
private void Picturemethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is PictureBox) { ((PictureBox)sender).Visible = false; }
    else { /* Do nothing or throw ArgumentException */ }
}
```